# Reactjs fetch data double enter

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a search form.but there is a problem.
Does not bring the data in the first enter result.
I need to do two or more enter.What's the problem?

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode === 13) {
         this.props.fetchUser(e.target.value)
         this.setUser(this.props.user)
       }
     }
    setUser(value) {
       this.setState({ user: value });
     }
```

Render

```
render() {
  const { user} = this.state;


  return (
     <input type="text" className="form-control btn-default " placeholder="Telefon Numarasını Giriniz.." onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          {
            user.length < 1
            ?
            <div> Please Enter Value !</div>
            :
            <div>
              {user.data.fname}
            </div>
          }
          </div>
        </div>    
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole element with the parent element?

Comment: post the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `charCode === 13` not `keyCode` as it is `onKeyPress`. Or you can use `.key`. If it's still not working, maybe try `onKeyDown` instead.

Comment: thank you but problem is not not to enter. When I enter handle KeyPress works but this.state.user does not receive data.This time it happens once you enter again.

Comment: Does `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` help ?